# Does oracleoverflow.com belong to the stackoverflow-area51 conglomerate

Tags: discussion

I have recently stumpled opon http://www.oracleoverflow.com/, but I am not sure if this site belongs to the stackoverflow, area51 (and what-else?) conglomerate, or is it a copy paste application by someone else?

I ask because I tried to associate my OpenID with that oracleoverflow.com site, but it didn't work. Later, I discovered, that in the bottom of the site, it said that the service is provided by "red gate" as opposed to "stack overflow internet services, inc".

Who knows more? I'd be happy, probably, if I *knew* what exactly my question is....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a StackExchange 1.0 site.

Before Area51 when people voted for new StackExchange sites, you could just buy one.

Comment: View the source and look for `<meta name="generator" content="StackExchange 0.9 (20100413135304-37b86aed49ad)">` at top of the file. If it's there it's an SE 1.0 site.